# Build of sodium-native on CentOS cloud is failing

Tags: linux, gcc, npm, centos7

I have installed node 10.16.3. I do not haveroot access. npm install sodium-native.

I have installed in my local account gcc 7.3.0 and I have set LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LD_RUN_PATH to the location of my local gcc. However, I'm still getting the below error. Is there a parameter I need to pass for node or the sodium package to use the gcc 7.3.0.
This is a CENTOS local account that has gcc 4.4.

```
CXX(target) Release/obj.target/sodium/binding.o
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++1y"
make: *** [Release/obj.target/sodium/binding.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory /home/mylocal/api/node_modules/sodium-native/build' gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error: make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/emedappc/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.59.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/home/mylocal/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node" "/home/mylocal/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/mylocal/api/node_modules/sodium-native
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

I started with current 'gcc' etc but slowly I have installed node, updated 'npm' locally. 'gcc' locally (I cannot change the global library) so I set export 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' to my 'gcc'.  I still think that node is not using the local 'gcc' I installed

Comment: *`unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++1y"`* - Red Hat supplies antique software. The compiler is too old, and does not recognize `-std=gnu++1y`. It looks like you need to build a modern GCC or Clang, and then point to it via something like `CC=/opt/gcc-9/gcc CXX=/opt/gcc-9/g++ make -j 4` (or however npm does it).

Comment: I figure out my issue to install it using a local gcc copy
env CC=/local/path/gcc-7.3.0-install/bin/gcc CXX=/local/path/gcc-7.3.0-install/bin/g++ npm install sodium-native

then to run node app.js
I had to use
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/local/path/gcc-7.3.0-install/lib/:/local/path/gcc-7.3.0-install/lib64